# Fetching all keys from Partitioned Coherent Cache

Tags: caching, distributed-caching, oracle-coherence, jcache

I am doing a project and my requirement is to basically implement a Coherence Cache Dashboard. The basic idea is to fetch all the keys stored in the Coherent Cache. Is there a command or any other way to fetch all cache  keys from distributed coherent cache?

```
    public void printAllCache(){

    Cache<String, String> cache = cacheManager.getCache(CACHENAME, 
      String.class, String.class);

    Iterator<Cache.Entry<String,String>> allCacheEntries= cache.iterator();
    while(allCacheEntries.hasNext()){
      Cache.Entry<String,String> currentEntry = allCacheEntries.next();
      System.out.println("Key: "+currentEntry.getKey()+" Value: "+ 
      currentEntry.getValue());
    }

      return returnProperties;

    }
```

By doing this, i can iterate over cache keys created by the current cache manager. But, how can I find keys created by other cache managers in a partitioned coherent cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple command:

```
 NamedCache<String, String> cache = CacheFactory.getCache(CACHENAME, String.class, String.class);
 Set<String> keys = cache.keySet();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But using this command can I retrieve keys of a partitioned cache? I think this will only work for NamedCache

Comment: The PartitionedCache is the specific implementation for the distributed cache but client side when you want  to use it you can use the class CacheFactory to obtain a NamedCache reference for the partitioned cache.
You don't use the partitioned cache but at client side you should use the named cache class that hides the real implementation.
I update my script.
Try it!

Comment: Okay. Is there any UNIX script for the same which I could run to retrieve the keys?

Comment: No, you have to use the API .
Then there's the Coherence query language to read coherence data from wlst console.

Comment: Yeah. I am trying to use Cohql query in Production. But i am getting this error "no storage-enabled nodes exist for service partitionedcache" when I am trying to use the command  - select * from "cachename". Although, the cache contains some data.